# I need to add circle in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image: i need to add this circle in my app in flutter]

I would like to add this circle to my app in Flutter. I tried to write this code, but the result was not as shown in the picture:

```
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
        width: width,
        height: 300,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 156, 122),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(500),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(500),
          ),
          image: DecorationImage(
            opacity: 0.2,
            image: AssetImage('images/back.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: const Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text(
              "LOGO",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

this is the result:

[image: this result]

Comment: Isn't it better to edit the image instead of cropping the image using code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CustomPainter, the full code for that is here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: _FondoOvalo(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _FondoOvalo extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();

    paint.color = Colors.indigo;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint.strokeWidth = 2;

    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.45);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width*0.5,   
      size.height*0.6,  
      size.width,       
      size.height*0.45); 
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

you can customize the segment in quadraticBezierTo, this allows you to make a curve from a current point to an end point

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).